# Would a google cloud platform machine with many different CPUs allow me to run API requests through several differen IP addresses?

Tags: api, parallel-processing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ip-address

I am trying to query public utility data from an API (oasis.caiso.com) with a threaded script in R. Apparently this API will refuse requests from certain IP addresses if too many are made. Therefor I need to run many different API requests in parallel across different IP addresses, and am wondering if a machine with many different CPUs on google cloud platform will allow this?

I was looking at the n1-highcpu-96 option from this page: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types

If this is a poor solution can anyone suggest another distributed computing solution that can scale to allow dozens or even hundreds of API queries simultaneously from different IPs?

Comment: You're asking for community help to create a DDS or something similar ?

Comment: Not sure which of these (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDS) acronyms DDS stands for but I am trying to distribute a lengthy API query process (scraping solar data) that usually takes a week into a shorter period of time.

Comment: I meant what Wikipedia abbreviates as `DDoS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I needed multiple IP to perform "light" API calls I would not scale vertically (with a machine having 96 core). I would create an [instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) with 50 or 100 or n Debian micro or small [preentible instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) with the size depending on the kind of computation you need to perform.

You can set up a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) loaded in the metadata or in a custom image that connects to the API server do what it has to do and save the result on a bucket and if the instance get a "API refuse" I would simply kill the instance automatically having the instances group creating a new one for me with *possibly* a new IP.

This I think is a possible easy solution to achieve what you want, but I guess there are multiple solutions.

> I am not sure what you are trying to achieve and I think you need to check first that it is legal and if the owner of the API agree.

Comment: Thank you, this looks about right.

I think I am going to opt to scale my one, single week process down to a dozen 12 hr processes (rather than hundreds of short processes) so as not to overwhelm the API nor the traffic it may receive.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, just double check you are allowed to do what you want to do. By the way please consider to upvote and accept the answer ir it helped you.

Comment: I tried, but have less than 15 reputation so it is not showing up. Thank you again.